# Facebook get username by id

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

this is how i get the user profile image by id

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100003959673716/picture?type=large
```

but this don't working for get name by id

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100003959673716/name
```

anyone have any solution for my case ?

i don't want to use PHP to get the name , because my web page need display a lot of facebook user current name & image , i have their facebook id , so i use html + js +jquery only in my page for this part , and my php is working for other part.

Comment: Get the user and parse the name from there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Answer (score 0):

have you ever tried "first_name"?

```
 var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/"+sender+"?access_token="+ config.token;
request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        alert(body.first_name);
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not get username without access token , it will give you authorizarion error :

```
 {
    error: {
    message: "An access token is required to request this resource.",
    type: "OAuthException",
    code: 104,
    fbtrace_id: "F5lPaiB3w9s"
    }
}
```

So you need to registered your app at facebook developer console : https://developers.facebook.com/